# Xamarin.Forms SQLite.net data execution

Tags: c#, sqlite, mobile, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have SQLite database generated in Sqlite Browser with imported Excel files.
It has few tables. Each table has same structure.

Columns are:

- Age
- 2000m
- 2000f
- 2500m
- 2500f
- ... etc.

All I need is to open this database in my Xamarin.Forms Shared project and execute 1 item per time.

Each cell includes 1 double number. I need to execute this number and send it to Label on screen.

I don't need to write anything to this database. Only read.

Best way I can imagine is to Execute SQL like:

```
Select 2000m From Bravo Where Age = 20.
```

Can someone help me with that?

Comment: Out of curiosity: why do you have several tables with the same structure? What do you mean execute 1 item per time? I don't think it makes sense in the context. Have you tried anything? In case you need a general tutorial: This website seems to have a tutorial, check their github project: http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/working-with/databases/

Comment: Forget about several tables. I'll add column with 1 more field from which result can depend.

Comment: Tutorials don't show how exactly i can get access to data and execute SQL.

Comment: Yes it does, it is directly on the page I sent you.

Comment: It shows how to create new database, but not how to use previously deployed.

Also it returns list. But how can i get only 1 item with number i need?

I was sitting around this tutorial for few days.

Comment: Ok if it is not possible for you to get from the example to your problem you might need to start further at the beginning, these are basics really. It is not possible for anyone at the internet to help you if you cannot provide the code you have produced so far or tell exactly what the problem is. 
E.g. you could start with the sample and change it so that it fits your problem.

Comment: Write 'database = DependencyService.Get<ISQLite> ().GetConnection ();' but don't do the create table part... and then change the method
public IEnumerable<TodoItem> GetItems () {
    return (from i in database.Table<TodoItem>() select i).ToList();
}
to your needs... Change return type and the select statement and so on...

Comment: Now i started from beginning. Again. Could you help me, please?
So, this part:
"database = DependencyService.Get<ISQLite> ().GetConnection ();"
let me to get my database. 
I'm using sqlite-net library. What should i change "ISQLite" for?

"IEnumerable<TodoItem> GetItems () { return (from i in database.Table<TodoItem>() select i).ToList(); }"
this part let's me to execute some data from my db.

TodoItem is file with my model of DB. Right?

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was with Windows Phone. Somehow it can't start SQLiteConnection.
But Android does, so iOS must too.

First of all i moved my DB to local path of application:

```
 public static string GetLocalFilePath(string filename)
        {
            string path = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
            string dbPath = Path.Combine(path, filename);

            CopyDatabaseIfNotExists(dbPath);

            return dbPath;
        }

        private static void CopyDatabaseIfNotExists(string dbPath)
        {
            if (!File.Exists(dbPath))
            {
                using (var br = new BinaryReader(Application.Context.Assets.Open("KDLife_mobileDB.db3")))
                {
                    using (var bw = new BinaryWriter(new FileStream(dbPath, FileMode.Create)))
                    {
                        byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
                        int length = 0;
                        while ((length = br.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                        {
                            bw.Write(buffer, 0, length);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate (bundle);

            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init (this, bundle);
            global::Xamarin.FormsMaps.Init(this, bundle);

            string dbPath = GetLocalFilePath("KDLife_mobileDB.db3");

            LoadApplication (new KDLife_mobile.App ());

            App.ScreenWidth = (int)Resources.DisplayMetrics.WidthPixels;
            App.ScreenHeight = (int)Resources.DisplayMetrics.HeightPixels;


        }
```

Then i opened connection:

```
public SQLiteConnection DBClass_conn()
        {
            database = new SQLiteConnection (DatabasePath);
            return database;
        }
```

Then i added SQLiteCommand:

```
SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(App.Database.DBClass_conn());
```

And query:

```
public string querytext(string q_table)
        {
            string sql = "SELECT \"2000f\" FROM Bravo WHERE Age = \"20\" AND Period = \"15\"";//, App.amount_gender, q_table, App.age;
            return sql;
        }
```

Then i just change CommandText and ExecuteScalar:

```
cmd.CommandText = querytext("Symphony");
string count = (string)cmd.ExecuteScalar<string>();
```

Right now it execute only 1 query, but it's not hard to make it more universal.